Construction of real numbers by rational nested intervals: how to show the chosen intervals satisfy the definition?
My analysis lecture notes require two properties in the definition of a sequence of rational nested intervals $(I_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = [a_n, b_n]$:
(1) $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: a_n \le a_{n+1} \lt b_{n+1} \le b_n$,
(2) $\forall \epsilon \gt 0: \exists n \in \mathbb{N}: b_n - a_n < \epsilon.$
The following sequence of nested intervals is used to construct $\sqrt 2$:
Let $x_0 := \frac{3}{2}$, and for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ define $x_{n} := \frac{1}{2}(x_{n-1} + \frac{2}{x_{n-1}})$. Then the sequence of rational intervals $(I_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$:= $[\frac{2}{x_n}, x_n]$ represents the real number $\sqrt 2$.
I can see that condition (1) is satisfied. But how does one formally show that condition (2) in the definition also holds?

If you compute $x_{n+1}-\frac2{x_{n+[}}$ in terms of $x_n,$ what do you get?

Looks like Newton's method for square roots.

@ThomasAndrews: one gets: $x_{n+1}-\frac{2}{x_{n+1}}=\frac{x_n-\frac{2}{x_n}}{2(x_n+\frac{2}{x_n})}.|I_n|$, meaning the length of the $n+1$-th interval is a fraction less than $1$ of the length of the $n$-th. I know this intuitively means the length of the interval approaches $0$ as $n$ grows toward $\infty$, so for every $\epsilon$ the length of the intervals will become smaller than $\epsilon$ at some $n$, but how am I supposed to write this formally in a way that shows condition (2) holds?

Actually, the fraction is $\frac{1}{2(x_n+2/x_n)}<\frac1{2}.$ It wouldn't be enough if the fraction was just $<1.$

@ThomasAndrews: I double-checked my calculation and I don't see my mistake. Are you sure about the fraction? Why wouldn't it be enough if the fraction was just $<1$?

I didn't say you made a calculation mistake. You made a deduction mistake. Your denominator is at least $2.$

Because if the fraction for $x_{n+1}$ is$1-\frac1{(n+1)^2},$ the product  $$(1-1/4)(1-1/9)(1-1/16)..\neq 0.$$ You don't need smaller than $\frac12,$ but  need an the fractions bounded away from $1$ to be sure the the product goes to $0.$

@ThomasAndrews: ok, thank you. It's now clear that my reasoning is nonsensical. It's obvious that if all one knows is that the fractions are merely less than $1$, it doesn't say anything about condition (2), since e.g. it's possible the lengths of the successive intervals are barely changing and never become infinitely small. Of course, condition (1) already says the fractions are $\leq 1$. What one must show is that the successive scaling-down eventually brings the length to approach zero.

@ThomasAndrews: unfortunately, for whatever reason somewhere in the back of my mind I assumed the fractions were constant, which they obviously aren't, so I was thinking "if one continuously scales down by the same factor which is less than one".

Yeah, it takes a while to,avoid that kind of error.

@ThomasAndrews: by the way, how can it be shown that the intersection of these rational intervals is empty (before $\mathbb{R}$ has been defined)?
